# can I use double asterisk ( ** ) as Exponentiation Operators in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I know Power function works in Oracle; however I need to test double asterisk ( ** )   as Exponentiation  Operators in Oracle PL/SQL.

```
select (2 **3) from dual;  ---there is an error.
```

if I put it into PL/SQL block, still error:

```
declare
 kkk number;
begin
 select (2**3) into kkk from dual;
end;
```

Comment: I don't see ** as a supported operator in oracle documentation. It seems the result of your "test" is that it doesn't work!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions112.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select (2 **3) from dual;` is not PL/SQL - that's plain SQL!

And `begin select (2**3) into kkk from dual; end;` is still SQL in PL/SQL.

You can use it, in pure PL/SQL see [PL/SQL Language Fundamentals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-65EAAB52-8E2C-45E1-B004-CA00A942FF0C)

```
DECLARE
  res NUMBER;
BEGIN
  res := 2 ** 3;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
END;
```

Comment: thanks @Wernfried Domscheit! Your answer solves my question: why I use ** in PL/SQL block still throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

No, the [Oracle SQL arithmetic operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Arithmetic-Operators.html#GUID-46CD9FD8-FC94-44BA-AA62-30A16063EAAE) are:

- The unary operators `+` and `-`, for positive and negative numbers; and
- The binary operators `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`, for addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

There is no exponentiation operator in Oracle SQL.

You can use [the `POWER(n2, n1)` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/POWER.html) to raise `n2` to the power of `n1`.

```sql
SELECT POWER(2,3) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| POWER(2,3) |
| --- |
| 8 |

As described in [@WernfriedDomscheit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74776378/1509264), you can use [the exponentiation operator in PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-65EAAB52-8E2C-45E1-B004-CA00A942FF0C) (but not if you switch from the PL/SQL scope back to the SQL scope with a `SELECT`/`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`MERGE` statement).